# Profibus with rpi master and slave

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, connect, master-slave

I am tasked with building profibus master and slave network using Rpi and Rs-485 convertor .

One Rpi will be master and other will be slave. I am using https://github.com/mbuesch/pyprofibus for  DP-stack to implement the same.

**How can I assign address to master and slave rpi boards to use in profibus initialization sequence**. It is not accepting the IP address given to the rpi boards

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you talk about IP addresses I think you may be mistaken Profibus with Profinet. If that's the case you might want to take a look at the Fieldbus drivers introduced in the Linux Kernel from version 5.2. I did not have time to test them but they should offer what you need.

If, on the contrary, you are indeed referring to Profibus I'm afraid there is nothing on the open-source front that you could use as a Profibus slave stack for the RPi. As you say, there is a master stack (PyProfibus) that works well.

If the target is to build a Profibus network for educational purposes or in-house use you can use the [BeagleBone Black or BBB](https://beagleboard.org/black) SBC, which is more or less the same cost as the RPi. Unfortunately, the Profibus stack software (both master and slave) does not run on Linux but on TI RTOS (a lightweight OS for several Texas Instruments processors). To comply with the hard real-time requirements of Profibus, this software takes advantage of TI's Sitara [PRU-ICSS](http://www.ti.com/processors/sitara-arm/applications/industrial-communications.html) (Programmable Real-Time Unit Industrial Communication Subsystem), which is, oversimplifying a bit, a couple of microcontrollers integrated together with Sitara's SoC. This means, obviously, this software won't be portable to any other hardware (other than TI's Sitara family).

If you decide to give it a try you will have to install TI's development environment. In-detail instructions can be found in TI's Processors Forums: [1](https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors/f/791/t/830322?tisearch=e2e-sitesearch) and [2](https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors/f/791/p/830896/3081076?tisearch=e2e-sitesearch&keymatch=profibus#pi320966=1).

On the hardware front, you will need either a couple of BBB boards or just the one and a Profibus Master or Slave (PLC or whatever device you have). If you are interfacing with a PLC or any other standard Profibus device (so not to another BBB board) you will also need a cheap (a couple of bucks) RS485 to TTL transceiver.

If you are willing to pay for hardware and/or licensing fees, the prospects are a bit brighter. The German company [Kunbus](https://www.kunbus.com/), well-known for its [Revolution Pi](https://revolution.kunbus.com/revolution-pi-series/) range of PLC-like-computers based on the Raspberry Pi, produce a [Profibus Slave Gateway](https://revolution.kunbus.com/gateways/). They also offer Profibus software for TI's Sitara processors that works on Linux and TI RTOS, but there are licensing fees or a fixed price you have to pay to purchase the library. And some time ago they were [thinking about](https://revolution.kunbus.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=192) releasing a Profibus Master software stack for the Revolution Pi, but as far as I can tell that came to nothing.

To complete my answer I will just mention that they were some projects in the past to implement a Profibus slave on several microcontrollers (from [Atmel](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/profibus) and [TI](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/106174)). I guess it should be possible to take what is available from those projects and successfully build a Profibus slave but unless you already have the MCU and programming/debugging tools or you are really into hardware prototyping, I doubt that endeavor would be easier or cheaper than the BBB solution referred above.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not affiliated with either Texas Instruments or Kunbus. All of the above is based on my own research, experience, and opinions. I did write the posts on TI's Processors Forum referred to above after adapting the examples that TI provides for more professional boards based on the same SoC myself. Note that TI does not offer support for Profibus on the BBB board. My goal was to find a low-cost platform to test and debug Profibus links on the cheap (around 50$ compared to 300$ for more professional boards or more than 600$ for most industrial products).

Comment: Thanks Marcos.  Curious, do you think this would work on the [Pocket Beagle](https://beagleboard.org/pocket)?  I'm surprised there is no way to program and communicate with the PRU's from Linux.  I was hoping for Python-PRU capability.

Comment: Hello rdtsc. I did some research on the Pocket Beagle and according to the documentation, the Profibus stack is indeed supported. I cannot guarantee the modifications I made for the BBB would work out of the box though. With some effort, I guess it should not be difficult. If you ever get a working Profibus device running on the PocketB I think it would be the smallest on the market. I would dig your Python-PRU for sure. The good thing about TI is you have a lot of documentation and support, have you looked at their Processors Forum?

Comment: Reviewing the documentation I've come across [this](http://octavosystems.com/octavo_products/osd335x-sm/#collapse_3870): *...the AM335x die in the OSD335x-SM is the same as the Die in the discrete TI device.  This means that the Pin MUX will work the same on the OSD335x-SM as it would on the discrete version. There are differences in the location and position of the signals, however. Please refer to OSD335x Family Pin Assignments page for ball map differences between OSD335x-SM and AM335x.*  I guess that means it should work out of the box.

Comment: Just to clear any confusion: you can access and work with the PRU from Linux, what you don't have is a Profibus software stack for free. I guess not that many hobbyists are interested anyway...

Comment: Michael Büsch contributes [pyProfibus](https://git.bues.ch/cms/automation/profibus.html) which may be helpful.  I'm currently working on a Profibus decoder for [Sigrok](https://sigrok.org).  There is interest, it is just few and far-between.  Thank you Marcos.

Comment: You're more than welcome. Yes, pyProfibus is great. I will be following your work on Sigrok. I researched a lot before porting TI's code to the BBB and I could not find any other available (and free of charge) alternatives. I guess the high cost of most commercial Profibus devices acts as a very high entry barrier.