# How to solve Bad File Descriptor for Linux and Modbus

Tags: linux, modbus, rs485

I am trying to setup a Half Duplex RS-485 communication using libmodbus on a Raspberry Pi running Raspian Buster, with a FTDI USB to Serial adapter. My FTDI adapter shows as ttyUSB0 when I run ls /dev/.

I tried the following sample code:

```
#include <modbus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   modbus_t *ctx  = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyUSB0", 19200, 'N', 8, 1);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create the libmodbus context\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode(ctx, MODBUS_RTU_RS485) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the serial port as RS-485\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "errno: %d\n (EBADF == 9)", errno);
        modbus_free(ctx);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compiled with `gcc test1.c -I/usr/include/modbus -lmodbus`.
And I get `errno` as `9`, or `EBADF`, even if I run this code with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very easy solution to your problem: just don't set `MODBUS_RTU_RS485`, quite likely you don't need it.

This mode is actually a workaround for devices without automatic (hardware) direction control. As you know, Modbus RTU works over a half-duplex RS485 link (only one device is allowed to talk while all others must be listening only), and hence requires an additional (to RX and TX) signal to control what device is writing to the bus at all times (direction control).

So you would only need to set `MODBUS_RTU_RS485` if your device lacks this feature, which is nowadays quite unlikely or if you are building your own transceiver. Most devices based on the FTDI chip, in particular, should have this feature since the chip itself has a TXDEN (transmit enable) pin. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56066933/11476836) for more details and a trick to expose the TXDEN signal to a non-default pin.

It is when you don't have this feature (one frequent scenario is when you want to use the embedded UART on your Rpi for Modbus over RS485, implementing your own transceiver) that you need a software (or hardware) workaround. And that's where `MODBUS_RTU_RS485` should come handy, repurposing the RTS flow control signal. Unfortunately, most serial drivers (including `ftdi_sio`, the one you are probably using) don't support this mode (refer again to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56066933/11476836) above).

Luckily, there are workarounds to the workaround: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922031/modbus-error-invalid-message-incomplete-message-received-expected-at-least-2/56923891#56923891) for a complete discussion. You can also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56106253/11476836) where I explained how to set up *libmodbus* with support for toggling the direction on the bus using a GPIO pin on a Rpi (also applicable to most SBCs, I've used this method successfully with a Pocket Chip computer, for instance).

You can find more background on this issue elsewhere: [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/libmodbus/rtjp2rzy_x8/discussion) and [here](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/issues/331).

Comment: Thanks Marcos, indeed I have found your answer some hours ago and I am going to try using TXDEN, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. From your question I understood you had a USB-to-RS485 converter; maybe you meant you have a USB UART on TTL levels that you're putting together with an RS485 transceiver. If that's the case (that was my case on the link where I rerouted the TXDEN signal to the TX LED) then you should be able to use that solution pretty easily. Otherwise you can try the software approach and use a GPIO pin. Good luck with your tinkering anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I have a USB to TTL and then a TTL to RS-485... I will solder a wire for the meantime, but I already purchased a USB to RS-485 adapter as it's so cheap and much cleaner.

Comment: OK, yes, it makes sense, you can find USB-to-RS485 converters for 10$. The transceiver is required if you want to use UARTS on an embedded platform like the Rpi. I had to do it, for instance, to implement a [Profibus slave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411758/11476836) on a BeagleBone Black SBC